# Reading Google Fit heart rate data with Fitness History API: different results on different watches

Tags: android, wear-os, google-fit

I'm developing some watch faces for Android Wear (minSdkVersion=21 and targetSdkVersion=23) and integrating the Google Fit API for Android.

I use Fitness.SensorsApi.add to read heart rate sensor data from a Huawei Watch and Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe to sync the sensor data into Google Fit. 
And it works: Updated data is correctly showing in the watch Google Fit app and in the web Google Fit page (https://fit.google.com/).

When I try to read the data back, using Fitness.HistoryApi.readData, on the same watch, it works perfectly.
This is the logcat output:

```
Range Start: Mar 7, 2017
Range End: Mar 8, 2017
Number of returned DataSets is: 1
Data returned for Data type: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
Data point:
    Type: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
    Start: 08.03 - 02:01:38
    End: 08.03 - 02:01:38
    Field: bpm Value: 82.0
Field: bpm
Field: 2
Field: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
mLastHeartBPM: 82
```

However, when I try to access the same heart rate data from another watch, a Sony Smartwatch 3 running the same software as the Huawei Watch (Android Wear 1.5 -  Google Play Services 10.2.98) it keeps reading old data from Google Fit. 
This is the logcat output:

```
Range Start: Mar 7, 2017
Range End: Mar 8, 2017

Number of returned DataSets is: 1
Data returned for Data type: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
Data point:
    Type: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
    Start: 07.03 - 04:31:13
    End: 07.03 - 04:31:13
    Field: bpm Value: 70.0
Field: bpm
Field: 2
Field: com.google.heart_rate.bpm
mLastHeartBPM: 70
```

As you can see, same startTime and endTime, but completely different result.
The data returned is an actual value present in Google Fit but it's an old one.

This is the function I use to access the Google Fit data

```
        private void getHeartBpm() {

        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "getHeartBpm()");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(VeertualiaFit.this, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if ((mGoogleApiClient != null)
                && (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())) {


            mHeartBpmRequested = true;

            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "=============== getHeartBpm(): QUERYING =========================");


            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date now = new Date();
            cal.setTime(now);
            long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

            java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));
            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");



            DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setLimit(1)
                    .build();


            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, readRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {

                    if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: "
                                + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
                        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                                if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getTimeInstance();

                                for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Data point:");
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tType: " + dataPoint.getDataType().getName());
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                    for(Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                                " Value: " + dataPoint.getValue(field));
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + field.getName());
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + field.getFormat());
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + dataPoint.getDataType().getName());

                                        mLastHeartBPM = (int)dataPoint.getValue(field).asFloat();
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tmLastHeartBPM: " + mLastHeartBPM);
                                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
                        if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: "
                                + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                            java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM - HH:mm:ss");

                            for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                                if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Data point:");
                                if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tType: " + dataPoint.getDataType().getName());
                                if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                for(Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                            " Value: " + dataPoint.getValue(field));
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + field.getName());
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + field.getFormat());
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "Field: " + dataPoint.getDataType().getName());

                                    mLastHeartBPM = (int)dataPoint.getValue(field).asFloat();
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "\tmLastHeartBPM: " + mLastHeartBPM);
                                    if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
            if(LOG_ENABLED) Log.d(TAG, "=================================================================");
        }
    }
```

I cannot find an explanation. 
Code seems to be correct, and it is based on Google samples.

Can somebody please give me a clue?

**UPDATE**
These are the DataReadResult values in the debugger:

**SONY**

```
DataReadResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, dataSets=[DataSet{d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm []}], buckets=[]}
```

**HUAWEI**

```
DataReadResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, dataSets=[DataSet{d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm [RawDataPoint{[70.0]@[1488981101916291248, 1488981101916291248](0,1)}]}], buckets=[]}

DataPoint{[70.0]@[1488981101916291248, 1488981101916291248,raw=0,insert=0](d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm r:heart_rate.bpm:HUAWEI WATCH:c528846c:ADPD153GGRI)}
```

The Sony SmartWatch 3 enters the `else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0)` part of the code, but the Datapoint is empty.

Comment: Try to test another data types other than the heart rate and check if you will still get different result. I'm not sure if this is a Device issue.

Comment: Hi KENdi. I'm already doing it. Values for Steps, Calories and Distance are correctly returned (give or take the time needed for Google Fit sync).

Comment: These are the DataReadresult values: 

SONY
DataReadResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, dataSets=[DataSet{d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm []}], buckets=[]}


HUAWEI
DataReadResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, dataSets=[DataSet{d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm [RawDataPoint{[70.0]@[1488981101916291248, 1488981101916291248](0,1)}]}], buckets=[]}

DataPoint{[70.0]@[1488981101916291248, 1488981101916291248,raw=0,insert=0](d:heart_rate.bpm:gms:default_heart_rate_bpm r:heart_rate.bpm:HUAWEI WATCH:c528846c:ADPD153GGRI)}

Comment: So only the heart rate is wrong?

Comment: I edited the original post for better readability.

Comment: It definitely seems so. Besides, until a few hours ago, the SW3 returned values were stale but some data was indeed returned. But now it is returning empty data, as you can see.